# What's an easy way of storing an array of numbers in Javascript that I can add/remove from?

Tags: javascript

In C# I would create a List then I could add and remove numbers very easily. Does identical functionality exist in Javascript, or do I have to write my own methods to search and remove items using a loop?

```
var NumberList = [];

NumberList.Add(17);
NumberList.Add(25);
NumberList.Remove(17);
```

etc.

I know I can use .push to add a number, so I guess it's really how to remove an individual number without using a loop that I'm looking for.

edit: of course, if there's no other way then I'll use a loop!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using the JQuery function `inArray();` combined with `splice()`.

`indexOf` and `inArray` seem to be identical, however `indexOf` isn't supported in IE6 or 7 as it turns out, so I had to either write my own or use JQuery, and I use JQuery anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The Array objet has this kind of method :

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push(12);
myArray.push(10);
myArray.pop();
```

All detail can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

To remove a specific value , some tricks are possible :

```
var id = myArray.indexOf(10); // Find the index
if(id!=-1) myArray.splice(id, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use splice and indexOf if you know that there is only one copy of the value that you want to remove and if there can be many copies then you have to use splice in a loop.

If you're using [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) then you can use:

```
array = _.without(array, 17);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove array element by value :

```
Array.prototype.removeByValue = function(val) {
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] == val) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var myarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
myarray.removeByValue("three");
console.log(myarray);  // ["one", "two", "four", "five"];
```

or in your case an array of numbers:

```
var myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
myarray.removeByValue(3);
console.log(myarray);  // [1, 2, 4, 5];
```

to remove by index you'll have to use [splice()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_splice.htm):

```
myarray.splice(2,1); //position at 2nd element and remove 1 element
console.log(myarray); // ["one", "two", "four", "five"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var NumberList = {};

NumberList[17] = true;
NumberList[25] = true;

delete NumberList[17];
```

This uses the "associative array"-characteristic of JavaScript objects to let you store and retrieve values by index in an object.

I used `true` as the value, but you can use anything you like, as it is not important (at least as per your example). You could of course store more useful things there. Using `true` has the nice side-effect that you can do an existence-check like this:

```
if (NumberList[25])  // evaluates to "true"

if (NumberList[26])  // evaluates to "undefined" (equivalent to "false" here)
```

The same would work with actual array objects, by the way.

```
var NumberList = [];

NumberList[17] = true;
NumberList[25] = true;

delete NumberList[17];
```

but these would not be "sparse" - `NumberList[25] = true` creates an 26-element array with all preceding array elements set to `undefined`.

Using objects instead is sparse, no additional members are created.

Comment: This was my idea also, but if the questioner really needs an array - this will not work.

Comment: Interesting, is delete supported in IE6+ browsers? Also, would there be any overhead associated if the range of numbers is say, 100,000?

Comment: @SLC As I explained, there would not be an overhead if you use objects (via `{}`). If you use arrays (via `[]`), there would be considerable overhead. And yes, `delete` is supported in IE6. It is just generally one of the lesser-known/used JS features.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the index of each added element (number). And then use splice to remove by index. [John has a good array remove function to remove by index](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/).

Something like:

```
var array = [];
var number = { val: 10, index: null };

// add to array
array.push(number.val);
number.index = array.length - 1;

// remove (using John's remove function)
array.remove(number.index);
// remove using splice
array.splice(number.index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want in-place removal, then `indexOf` and `splice` can be used together. To remove all occurrences of 17, use

```
var index;
while((index = NumberList.indexOf(17)) != -1) {
    NumberList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

If you don't care about in-place removals, then the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method can be used.

```
NumberList = NumberList.filter(function(number) {
    return number != 17;
});
```